# Remove string element in a list of strings if the first characters match with another string element in the list

Tags: python, list

I want to lookup and compare ***efficiently*** the string elements in a list and then remove those which are parts of other string elements in the list (with the same beginning point)

```
list1 = [ 'a boy ran' , 'green apples are worse' , 'a boy ran towards the mill' ,  ' this is another sentence ' , 'a boy ran towards the mill and fell',.....]
```

I intend to get a list which looks like this:

```
list2 = [  'green apples are worse' , ' this is another sentence ' , 'a boy ran towards the mill and fell',.....]
```

In other words, I want to keep the longest string element from those elements which start with the same first characters.

Comment: why is the last element `'a boy ran towards the mill and fell'` not removed then?

Comment: what have you tried, please ?

Comment: Please be more specific on your problem statement. That's what we have to understand your question. Be more detail.

Comment: If you sort them then the strings to be removed will be adjacent to the reason for removing them, which should allow for a quicker algorithm than the naive `O(n^2)`. Also, the string method `.startswith()` will help.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks. That's a good idea. I'll try. The order of the list matters cause it is actually a column in a df but I'll sort the df first by this column and try

Comment: If 'boy' was in list1, would you want that removed? The way your question is written, it wouldn't be removed because none of the other items begin with 'boy', but rather they begin with 'a boy'.

Comment: @Allen If there was a 'boy' element , it wont be removed in the given list example. It must match the first few characters of the string

Comment: @JohnColeman Posted it myself since you did not seem to come back. Feel free to edit/extend (I can also make it wiki) or to post your own version.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks. I am kind of busy at work now so didn't have time. +1 for your nice answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [John Coleman in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737130/remove-string-element-in-a-list-of-strings-if-the-first-characters-match-with-an#comment100033074_56737130), you can first sort the sentences and then compare consecutive sentences. If one sentences is a prefix of another, it will appear right before that sentences in the sorted list, so we just have to compare consecutive sentences. To preserve the original order, you can use a `set` for quickly looking up the filtered elements.

```
list1 = ['a boy ran', 'green apples are worse', 
         'a boy ran towards the mill', ' this is another sentence ',
         'a boy ran towards the mill and fell']                                                                

srtd = sorted(list1)
filtered = set(list1)
for a, b in zip(srtd, srtd[1:]):
    if b.startswith(a):
        filtered.remove(a)

list2 = [x for x in list1 if x in filtered]
```

Afterwards, `list2` is the following:

```
['green apples are worse',
 ' this is another sentence ',
 'a boy ran towards the mill and fell']
```

With O(nlogn) this is considerably faster than comparing all pairs of sentences in O(n²), but if the list is not too long, the much simpler solution by [Vicrobot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56737411/1639625) will work just as well.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds right. But what if I want the position of the element in list removed ? ( I am using this to remove rows from a df where list1 is a column)

Comment: I used sth like this: `for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(srtd, srtd[1:]))`  
Didnt work.

Comment: @NoHolidays I am not terribly well versed in Pandas, but you should be able to get the indices to retain using `[i for i, x in enumerate(list1) if x in filtered]`. If you `enumerate` the `zip`, you only get the indices in the sorted list, which might be different.

Answer (score 3):

This is a way you can achieve that:-

```
list1 = [ 'a boy ran' , 'green apples are worse' , 'a boy ran towards the mill' ,  ' this is another sentence ' , 'a boy ran towards the mill and fell']
list2 = []
for i in list1:
    bool = True
    for j in list1:
        if id(i) != id(j) and j.startswith(i): bool = False
    if bool: list2.append(i)
>>> list2
['green apples are worse', ' this is another sentence ', 'a boy ran towards the mill and fell']
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a slight ambiguity in the way you worded the question about how you'd want to handle `['a','ab','ac','add']`. I'm assuming you'd want `['ab','ac','add']`.

The below additionally assumes that you don't have any empty strings. That's not a good assumption.

Basically, we're building a tree out of the input values, and only keeping the leaf nodes. This is probably the most complex way to do it. I *think* it has the potential to be the most *efficient*, but I'm not certain <del>and that's not what you asked for anyway</del>.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
from typing import Collection, Dict, Generator, Iterable, List, Union

# Exploded is a recursive data type representing a culled list of strings as a tree of character-by-character common prefixes. The leaves are the non-common suffixes.
Exploded = Dict[str, Union["Exploded", str]]

def explode(subject:Iterable[str])->Exploded:
    heads_to_tails = defaultdict(list)
    for s in subject:
        if s:
            heads_to_tails[s[0]].append(s[1:])
    return {
        head: prune_or_follow(tails)
        for (head, tails)
        in heads_to_tails.items()
    }

def prune_or_follow(tails: List[str]) -> Union[Exploded, str]:
    if 1 < len(tails):
        return explode(tails)
    else: #we just assume it's not empty.
        return tails[0]

def implode(tree: Exploded, prefix :Iterable[str] = ()) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    for (head, continued) in tree.items():
        if isinstance(continued, str):
            yield ''.join((*prefix, head, continued))
        else:
            yield from implode(continued, (*prefix, head))

def cull(subject: Iterable[str]) -> Collection[str]:
    return list(implode(explode(subject)))

print(cull(['a','ab','ac','add']))
print(cull([ 'a boy ran' , 'green apples are worse' , 'a boy ran towards the mill' ,  ' this is another sentence ' , 'a boy ran towards the mill and fell']))
print(cull(['a', 'ab', 'ac', 'b', 'add']))
```

**EDIT:**
I flattened some of the calls, I hope it's easier to read and reason about this way.
It's bugging me that I can't figure out the run-time complexity of this process. I *think* it's O(nm) where m is the length of the overlapping prefixes, compared to O(nm log(n)) for a string comparison...

**EDIT:**
I started [this other question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/222877/200133) in Code Review, hoping someone could help me figure out the complexity a little. Someone there pointed out that the code as written didn't actually work: `groupby` is a junk by any sane interpretation of its name. I've swapped out the above code, and it's a little easier to read this way as well.

**EDIT:**
Ok, I've imported some of the excellent suggestions for CR. At this point I'm pretty sure I'm right about the runtime complexity being better than a sort-based option.